# Running Linux on Old PC

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lightweight GUI Linux distribution for really old computer](https://superuser.com/questions/73912/lightweight-gui-linux-distribution-for-really-old-computer)

I have an old PC with 196MB RAM, 20GB HDD, 466MHz Intel Celeron processor.

I want this PC to run 24/7 for torrent download/uploading and have RDP access to my other computers (Ubuntu and XP) in network.

I tried installing Kubuntu 9.10, but installation didn't proceed.

Which version of Linux version can work for me to run above applications?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more detail about why installation of Kubuntu 9.10 *didn't proceed*

Comment: Installation hangs on that machine, I left it overnight but no luck. But Windows XP works on that machine.

Answer (score 3):

[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.com/) is specially tailored for older hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I used only Ubuntu from last two years. The package manager is a nice one with Ubuntu. I don't know how we can add new applications to other versions of Linux. I'm trying Lubuntu, hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

[**Lubuntu**](http://lubuntu.net/), which I'd personally recommend because today's support for Ubuntu is rather good and the package-management is easy etc.

> Lubuntu is a fast, lightweight and energy-saving variant of Ubuntu using the LXDE (Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment) desktop. It is intended to have **low-resource system requirements** and is designed primarily for netbooks, mobile devices and **older PCs**.
>
> A Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MiB of RAM is probably a bottom-line configuration that may yield slow yet usable system with Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'm downloading it, let me try Lubuntu.